# SQL ACCESS - Left Join ? View All days of the month

Tags: sql, join

I try to manage a delivery team. That's why, i want to display a table . The first line will be completed by day. And the following rows will be filled with the states and their durations . The row "date" must contain all days of the month . Even if nobody works.

```
- First table (typeState) -
deliveryStatusDuration  //State Time (seconds)  INTEGER
deliveryStatus  //Type Status                   INTEGER
startStatus  //Start of the state               DATE
endStatus  //End of the state                   DATE
deliveryCarNum  //deliverer identifier          INTEGER


- Second table (dateTable) -
dateInt // Just an integer (from 1 to 31)       INTEGER
```

My SQL Request :

```
SELECT SUM(deliveryStatusDuration) AS DURATION, deliveryStatus, datetable.dateInt
FROM datetable                      
LEFT JOIN typeState ON datetable.dateInt = DAY(typeState.startStatus)
WHERE deliveryCarNum = :CarNum AND
startStatus >= :DateStart AND
endStatus <= :DateEnd AND   
(
 typeState.startStatus Is Null OR
 typeState.deliveryStatus Is Null OR
 datetable.dateInt <= DAY(:DateEnd)   
)   
GROUP BY datetable.dateInt, deliveryStatus
```

I know it must change the "Left Join" but I do not see how ?

The goal , whatever the month: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... [last day of the month]
..............................................................................
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sample input and output would be very helpful here.  "A picture is worth a thousand words" definitely holds true for SO SQL questions.

Comment: I use SQL in FastReport, do you know ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(BB.deliveryStatusDuration) AS DURATION, BB.deliveryStatus,     
 AA.dateInt
FROM 

(select dateInt FROM datetable ) AA LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT startStatus, deliveryStatus, deliveryStatusDuration FROM typeState WHERE deliveryCarNum = :CarNum AND
  startStatus >= :DateStart AND
  endStatus <= :DateEnd  
) BB ON AA.dateInt = DAY(BB.startStatus) WHERE 
1=1 AND (
BB.startStatus Is Null OR
BB.deliveryStatus Is Null OR
AA.dateInt <= DAY(:DateEnd) ) 


GROUP BY AA.dateInt, BB.deliveryStatus ORDER BY AA.dateInt
```

Comment: I didn't need to create dates because i have my dates table

Comment: that is only a integer value contained table. You need to create the dates from that table using any query like `concat(1, month(), Year())` and increment it one by one. OR you can use the dynamic date creation where all dates being generated

Comment: But it's work with Integer . The issue is : If you take the table up in my topic, the date result is :  1,2,4,12  But i want 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 13....31

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar to this and came up with 2 options;

> Option 1

You can create dates in Excel like '2016-01-01' until the date you want and dump these values into a DateDefinition table. Then, you can join your query with this table.

> Option 2

You can have a CTE to create a sequence of dates for you and then join your query with that. A common table expression that creates the dates between two given dates is like the following:

```js
Declare @todate datetime, @fromdate datetime
Select @fromdate='2016-01-01', @todate='2016-12-31'
 
;With DateSequence( Date ) as
(
    Select @fromdate as Date
        union all
    Select dateadd(day, 1, Date)
        from DateSequence
        where Date < @todate
)
 
--select result
Select * from DateSequence option (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

Note that the SELECT statement after WITH block is where you should join generated dates with your query.

> UPDATE 1

To the poster; can you check if the following works ?

```js
SELECT SUM(deliveryStatusDuration) AS DURATION, deliveryStatus, datetable.dateInt
FROM datetable                      
LEFT JOIN typeState ON datetable.dateInt = DAY(typeState.startStatus)
WHERE deliveryCarNum = :CarNum AND
(
 startStatus >= :DateStart AND
 endStatus <= :DateEnd AND   
 datetable.dateInt <= DAY(:DateEnd)
)   
GROUP BY datetable.dateInt, deliveryStatus
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Your dates table is just integers from 1 to 31. You should not implement it this way because not all months have same number of days. You should also consider leap years.

Comment: As in the WHERE clause you have two dates defined, your join only works for the dates found in typestate table. WHERE clause should only contain reference to datetable

Comment: Number of day in the month and leap years are managed with the software, no problem.  My request works, but it doesn't select null day .        I have : 1,2,4,12 .  I want : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,..31

Comment: Check UPDATE 1 above

Comment: Can you please send sample data from both of the tables?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QUILC.png                                                                       http://i.stack.imgur.com/qMO0D.png

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need. However, you should consider paying attention to naming conventions. I also think you have many repetitions in your query.

```js
SELECT SUM(deliveryStatusDuration) AS DURATION, 
    deliveryStatus, 
    datetable.dateInt
FROM datetable                      
LEFT JOIN typeState ON 
 datetable.dateInt = DAY(typeState.startStatus) 
 AND typeState.deliveryCarNum=:CarNum
 AND (
   typeState.startStatus Is Null OR
   typeState.deliveryStatus Is Null OR
   datetable.dateInt <= DAY(:DateEnd)
  )
 AND
  typeState.startStatus >= :DateStart
 AND
  typeState.endStatus >= :DateEnd
GROUP BY datetable.dateInt, deliveryStatus
ORDER BY dateInt
```

Comment: Thank for your help.. I have "unsupported join expression" error

Comment: Which database engine are you running on?

Comment: I made a mistake with one of the column names. Updated my answer. Can you check again?

Comment: I use SQL2 with MS ACCESS 2016

Comment: "unsupported join expression"  Again

Comment: It takes a "WHERE" condition no ?

Comment: Where condition in in the join